# Eventstore: How do I setup an persistent subscriptions client correctly?

Tags: c#, event-sourcing, eventstoredb

I'm using EventStoreDB V20 and I’m trying to setup a persistent subscription on my local dev machine. On the dashboard I can see the persistent subscription listed but the handler never gets called.

I'm using these nugets:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/EventStore.Client.Grpc/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/EventStore.Client.Grpc.PersistentSubscriptions/20.10.0

I run EventStore in docker:

```
docker run --name esdb-node -it -p 2113:2113 -p 1113:1113 -e EVENTSTORE_DEV=true eventstore/eventstore:latest --insecure --run-projections=All --enable-atom-pub-over-http
```

For appending the events, I do:

```
await eventStoreClient.AppendToStreamAsync(
    aggregate.Id.ToString(),
    aggregate.Version == 0 ? StreamRevision.None : StreamRevision.FromInt64(aggregate.Version),                            events);
```

Creating and subscribe to persistent subscription:

```
var client = new EventStorePersistentSubscriptionsClient(new EventStoreClientSettings {

    CreateHttpMessageHandler = () =>
        new HttpClientHandler
        {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
                (message, certificate2, x509Chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true // ignore https
        },
        ConnectivitySettings = new EventStoreClientConnectivitySettings
        {
            Address = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:2113?Tls=false&TlsVerifyCert=false")
        }});

        await client.CreateAsync("all", "TestGroup", new PersistentSubscriptionSettings(startFrom: StreamPosition.End));

        await SubscribeAsync(client);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static Task<PersistentSubscription> SubscribeAsync(EventStorePersistentSubscriptionsClient client)
    {
        return client.SubscribeAsync("all", "TestGroup",
            (subscription, evt, retryCount, cancelToken) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Received: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(evt.Event.Data.Span));

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });
    }
```

`Console.WriteLine` gets never called. What do I need to change?

Comment: Do you have the stream named `all`?

Comment: no, I really wanted $all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems to be set up correctly, but I doubt you have the stream with the name `all`. If you are trying to create a persistent subscription for the `$all` stream, it is not possible. You can only have a catch-up subscription on the `$all` stream.